# Does the Dueling Fighting Style prevent using a shield?

Tags: dnd-5e, shield, fighting-style

The Dueling fighting style doesn't seem to state anything about shields, stating that the character can only wield one weapon while fighting to gain the benefit. Does a shield count as a weapon or otherwise stop the damage bonus from occurring?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

No! The shield is not a weapon, this is designed to be a sword and board feature.

Shield is definitely not a weapon (no weapon stats), and there are currently no enchantments to make it a weapon. This is a feature designed for a brawler style (hand free for grappling) or a sword and board fighter.

Comment: Forgot the spellsword, who'd want a free hand for somatic components.

Answer (score 32):

Jeremy Crawford (D&D designer at Wizards of the Coast) tweeted that [dueling works with a shield](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/557812995108372480):

> > "does the duelling [sic] fighting style work with sword and shield?"
>
> It sure does!

This tweet was formalized into the Sage Advice Compendium as follows:

> **Is the Dueling fighting style intended to support a shield?**
> Yes. A character with the Dueling option usually pairs a one-handed weapon
> with a shield, a spellcasting focus, or a free hand.
> (Ref: SA Compendium, v 2.3, 2019, p.3)

Answer (score 0):

A shield is armor, not a weapon so it works while wielding a shield. The fighting style was probably even created to be used with a weapon in one hand and a shield in the other.