# Does the Tavern Brawler Feat mean you have to choose between Shield or Duelist?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, shield, fighting-style

> **Tavern Brawler**
>
> Accustomed to rough-and-tumble fighting using whatever weapons happen to be on hand, you gain the following benefits:
>
> - [...]
> - *You are proficient with improvised weapons*.
> - [...]

Now, this would technically turn a Shield into an improvised weapon, with which you are proficient, that deals 1d4 damage. **Does this make the Fighter's Duelist Fighting Style incompatible with a Shield if you get the Tavern Brawler feat?**

> **Duelist** (Fighting Style)
>
> Gain +2 bonus to damage rolls when wielding a melee weapon in one hand and *no other weapon*.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: The full text of a feat probably falls into the domain of copyright infringement. Please ellipsis out portions that aren't relevant to this question.

Comment: Is your concern that anything you touch immediately is treated as an improvised weapon and thus would disbar you from gaining the bonus from Duelist simply because you have a shield in your hand?

Comment: If your character have Tavern Brawler, why are you ever hitting foes with a shield? Why not just punch them or kick them? Same attack roll, same damage.

Comment: @DerekStucki a point of semantics: a better verb would be "elide"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### By strict RAW no, it would not make it incompatible.

There are a few reasons for this:

1. Improvised weapons are not weapons per-se, they don't have weapon stats* and they are not listed in the weapon category.
2. The reason for the *no other weapon* in the description is for the two-weapon fighting and two-handed options, though the second one is moot for this question.
3. By a strict RAW** you cannot use two-weapon fighting since the shield is not a *weapon* (no bonus action to attack with a shield as an improvised weapon).

> **Duelist:** Gain +2 bonus to damage rolls when wielding a melee weapon in one hand and **no other weapon**.
>
> **Two-weapon Fighting:** When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee **weapon** that you’re holding in one hand, you can use
> a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that
> you’re holding in the other hand.

*- [This](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/does-the-dueling-fighting-style-prevent-using-a-shield?rq=1) question shed some light in this. 
**- [Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/729789771560591360?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) stated that the intention is that two-weapon fighting can only be done by using *weapons*.

> Dual Wielder is intended to work with **actual weapons**. Using the feat
> with improvised weapons is up to the DM.

#### It is a DM decision on a more lax RAW interpretation.

As you can see, by strict RAW, the central issue is the two-weapon fighting feature. Therefore, if the DM consider that improvised weapon can be used with two-weapon fighting it is up to the DM to resolve this conflict.

Comment: So glad you answered this properly! In addition, this tweet from crawford: https://mobile.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/588513981729411072?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw might help clear up confusion that while a shield is not and never can be a Weapon (has no weapon stats or tags) it can be used improvisationally to make a melee weapon attack with it even though it still remains a shield the whole time.

Answer (score 4):

I think the conceptual problem is here

> Now, this would technically turn a Shield into an improvised weapon

which is inaccurate. An improvised weapon is defined on PHB 147 to be

> An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands

A shield (which isn't a proper weapon) can be wielded, so it's an improvised weapon. How skilled your character is at using it as a weapon has no bearing on its weapon-ness, the way a wizard poorly wielding a greatsword is still using a weapon.

So, consider a duelist with a shield. They're holding a real weapon in one hand, and a potential improvised weapon in the other.

**If the duelist also has Tavern Brawler, then they're merely good at said improvising; it doesn't fundamentally change the duelist-shield situation.**

So, can a duelist use a shield and the Duelist style? The answer is yes, because the shield isn't listed in the Weapons table.