# Could a Duelist Fighter wield Alchemist's Fire in their offhand and retain the Benefits of the Dueling fighting style?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, fighting-style

So, under the Fighter's fighting styles, Dueling says

> "When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other
>   weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon."

I was wondering if that fighter could wield Alchemist's Fire in their offhand and still gain the benefits of Dueling for their main weapon- although AF does damage, it is classified under "Adventuring Gear". It says that when you make the attack, you treat it as an improvised weapon-

> "Make a ranged attack against a creature or object, treating the
>   alchemist's fire as an improvised weapon."

Would it always count as an improvised weapon, or just for the duration of the attack?

Comment: This is a really interesting query, but you've got a few separate questions in here that should be separated into their own. Which are you looking for, and if it's all, it may be better to do them separately. I'm reading the following: Can a Duelist fighter wield Alchemist's fire in their offhand? Does wielding the alchemist fire count for Dueling? Do wands/magic items count as weapons for Dueling?

Comment: Okay, I've gone in and clarified the question- I hope that settles things. What I'm looking for is basically "Can a Duelist Fighter use Alchemist's Fire in their offhand while still gaining the Duelist benefit for their main weapon."

Answer (score 18):

## Yes

You gain the benefit of the Dueling Fighting Style with your weapon when you hold an improvised weapon in your other hand.

> #### Improvised Weapons
>
> [...] An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a dead goblin. [...]
>
> [*System Reference Document 5.1*, page 65](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=65)

Any object that is not a weapon could be an improvised weapon, including a shield, a spell component pouch, or a flask of alchemist's fire.

[You can wield a shield or hold a spell component pouch and benefit from the Dueling Fighting Style](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45094/does-the-dueling-fighting-style-prevent-using-a-shield), so the logic should follow for a flask of alchemist's fire.

> #### Dueling
>
> When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons, you gain a +2 bonus to damage rolls with that weapon.
>
> [*System Reference Document 5.1*, page 24](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf#page=24)

While you can use the alchemist's fire as an improvised weapon, you could use anything as an improvised weapon; that doesn't make it a weapon.

If the Dueling Fighting Style required your other hand to be empty, it would say so.

Comment: I would add that the dueling specifies wielding a melee weapon, even if an improvised weapon is considered a weapon, how do you differentiate between it being a melee and a ranged weapon? Seems alchemist's fire is something you throw anyway, not used for melee.

Answer (score 7):

## NO

As you stated in Dueling (PHB, 72)

> When you are wielding a melee weapon in one hand and no other weapons

And that Alchemist's Fire is listed under Adventuring Gear (PHB, 150), but it is clearly intended to be an improvised weapon, per the book as well (PHB, 150-151)

> ...treating the alchemist's fire as an improvised weapon

And Improvised Weapons are under the Weapons list from PHB, 147.

> An improvised weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a wagon wheel, or a dead goblin.

Other items under Adventuring Gear are things like ammunition and I think it's clear that for those and for Alchemist Fire, Acid, etc. that they are improvised weapons when being used. Which is now why I will discuss the difference between holding an object in your hand and wielding an improvised weapon in your hand.

The difference is that the alchemical fire is basically a grenade. It's an object until activated (thrown) but the intent is that it's a weapon.

### Holding vs Wielding

**Holding**

If you're just holding with no intent to use, the RAW would likely point to allowing the Dueling style as you aren't planning on using what you're holding as a weapon.

**Wielding**

However, if you intend to use the object in your hand as a weapon, then you would no longer be Dueling.

### Discussion

While a DM could allow this based on the looseness of the rules, they are ignoring the spirit of the Dueling Fighting Style: which is that you are wielding a one-handed weapon and nothing else. If your offhand is holding something that you intend to use as a weapon, then you are no longer Dueling.

In addition, there isn't a RAW way to get an offhand attack unless they use an Action Surge which limits how often this could be done or the instances in which it may be a concern. It still is the equivalent of having another weapon 'ready' if something were to happen to the primary weapon.

You can try and do a Deception check against your DM to convince them that the item you're holding isn't intended to be an improvised weapon, but that DC may be pretty high.

That being said, as long as you don't do both on your turn then I don't think it affects overall balance much. You're only removing the free action(?) to pull the flask out before throwing it. Not a huge deal, just seems more "duelist" to not do it. Unless it's one of those grenade duels.

Comment: You can not _use_ the Alchemist's Fire in the same turn (except for action surge), so does it really matter?

Comment: @András That's a good point, but Action Surge IS a thing. But i'll add that.

Comment: Improvised weapons aren't a very good argument. You can use dueling style with a shield in the other hand, and shields are also improvised weapons. (As is pretty much anything)

Comment: Heck, an improvised weapon isn't a weapon by definition. If it were a weapon, it wouldn't be an improvised weapon.

Comment: That's why I talk about Intent. If you intend to use your shield as a shield, then there's no Dueling issue. If you intend to use your shield as an improvised weapon, you are now holding weapons in both hands.

Comment: When the rules talk about "a weapon" it means a simple/martial weapon. A chair isn't suddenly a weapon just because you decide to attack with it. See also these tweets: ["Dual Wielder is meant to work (RAI) with a melee weapon or an equivalent, not something like a shield."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/588425967447609344) ["Weapon Bond works with a bona fide weapon ("Behold, my sword!"), not an improvised weapon ("Look, a stool!")."](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/719958571908218882)

Comment: I admit that I am going more with spirit of the rule then as written rule. While improvised weapons are listed as a subheading of Weapons in the PHB, the objects we're talking about are objects in the list of objects. But c'mon, you're using those things as weapons! It's choose your weapon in a duel, not choose your weapons :)

Comment: @Doval You could make that an answer with the tweets as source. RAW, yes. RAI, no, see these tweets.

Answer (score 5):

If we try to interpret Rules-as-Written here, we need a solid definition of when an improvised weapon is a weapon.

There are two possibilities for this:

1. An improvised weapon is a weapon for the entire turn *if you attack with it*.
2. An improvised weapon is a weapon *only during the attack using it*.

Note that it always being a weapon is not on this list - we know that isn't true since Dueling works while wielding a shield (and a shield can be used as an improvised weapon, so if it were always considered a weapon Dueling would not apply)

Clearly though, #2 leads to some sticky situations - it'd be objectively better to wield a dagger-like object than to wield a dagger (proficiency notwithstanding).

Thus, we should consider as #1 - and **you cannot gain the benefits of Dueling if you choose to attack with anything other than your Dueling weapon.**

---

Personally I would go even farther and say that a *weapon* shouldn't be considered a weapon unless you attack with it during a turn - why should holding a shield you're not using to attack be any different than holding a dagger you're not using to attack?
But that's not RAW or RAI.

Comment: an improvised weapon is not a weapon. using the rules you can make one attack dealing 1d4 damage with them. but they do not become weapons, not for one instant.

Comment: @Mindwin, would you allow a lvl5 Fighter to attack with a longsword (held in one hand) and with a tree branch (held in the other hand) and gain the benefits of Dueling on one or both of those attacks?

Comment: none of the above. I never mentioned dueling. Just that an improvised weapon is never a weapon, not for one instant.

Comment: @Mindwin "improvised weapon" has the word "weapon" right in it.  You can even have improvised thrown weapons (hucking a rock) and improvised melee weapons (swinging with a rock).  Improvised weapons that resemble non-improvised weapons are even treated as the non-improvised weapon they resemble (chair leg->club, for example).  Insisting that they aren't weapons...?

Comment: @BenBarden Fool's gold also has the word "gold" in it.

Comment: @BenBarden beware the red herrings. For they are plenty and deceitful.